# Inserting multiple rows into the database from the same html form

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, wamp

I want to insert differently i.e. multiple entries into the database, but input is taken from the same form.

I have a form called questionForm. It is a static form, and has a text field for inserting question and **corresponding text fields** like **marks allotted** for that question, **complexity level** of that question, **tag1 to tag8** (keywords in that question) present in that question, etc.

Now i want that **each** of these questions be inserted in my database when the form is submitted. **But not before the tags of each of the question entered in the form are compared to the tags of each question in the database to ensure that there are no duplicates**. How do i do this.

I know to insert an entry into the db via a simple form. Could someone assist me please.

I have reached almost halfway with the coding now. I am able to insert the entries into the form now, but it does not check properly for duplicates. Here's my question form and php file -

**Question form**
    
     Test Quest

#### Enter Subject Details.

Month and Year: Semester: Subject: Branch:

```
<h3>Enter Questions</h3><br>
<h3>Question 1: Five marks each.<br></h3>


a) <input type="text" name="field1[]" size=45>* Marks: <input type="text" name="field2[]"> Complexity:<input type="text" name="field3[]"> Chapter No.: <input type="text" name="field4[]"> Tags: <input type="text" name="field5[]" size=10> <input type="text" name="field6[]"   size=10> <input type="text" name="field7[]" size=10> <input type="text" name="field8[]" size=10> <input type="text" name="field9[]" size=10> <br>

b) <input type="text" name="field1[]" size=45>* Marks: <input type="text" name="field2[]"> Complexity:<input type="text" name="field3[]"> Chapter No.: <input type="text" name="field4[]"> Tags: <input type="text" name="field5[]" size=10> <input type="text" name="field6[]"   size=10> <input type="text" name="field7[]" size=10> <input type="text" name="field8[]" size=10> <input type="text" name="field9[]" size=10> <br>

<p><input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input type='reset' name='Cancel' value='Cancel' /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**quest.php**

```
include('connectionfile.php');

$cnt = count($_POST['field1']);
$my= $_POST['my'];
$sem= $_POST['sem'];
$subj= $_POST['subj'];
$branch= $_POST['branch'];

if ($cnt > 0) {

        for ($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++) 
    {

    $t1 = $_POST['field5'][$i]; 
    $t2 = $_POST['field6'][$i];
    $t3 = $_POST['field7'][$i];
    $t4 = $_POST['field8'][$i];
    $t5 = $_POST['field9'][$i];

$result = "SELECT * FROM paper WHERE (((`tag1` LIKE '%".$t1."%') OR (`tag1` LIKE '%".$t2."%') OR (`tag1` LIKE '%".$t3."%') OR (`tag1` LIKE '%".$t4."%') OR (`tag1` LIKE '%".$t5."%')) AND ((`tag2` LIKE '%".$t2."%') OR (`tag2` LIKE '%".$t3."%') OR (`tag2` LIKE '%".$t4."%') OR (`tag2` LIKE '%".$t5."%')) AND ((`tag3` LIKE '%".$t3."%') OR (`tag3` LIKE '%".$t4."%') OR (`tag3` LIKE '%".$t5."%')) AND ((`tag4` LIKE '%".$t4."%') OR (`tag4` LIKE '%".$t5."%')) AND ((`tag5` LIKE '%".$t5."%')) ) ;" ; // which checks if the tags in that question match with the tags of any other question in the db.

$sql= mysql_query($result) OR die(mysql_error()) ;

$duplicates = mysql_num_rows($sql);


if( $duplicates > 0)
echo "No entry entered for Entry #$i since it may lead to duplicates."; // no entry is inserted in insertArr[] if it leads to duplication

else
  $insertArr[] = "('" .$_POST['field1'][$i]. "', '" .$_POST['field2'][$i]. "', '" .$_POST['field3'][$i]. "', '" .$_POST['field4'][$i]. "', '" .$_POST['field5'][$i]. "', '" .$_POST['field6'][$i]. "', '" .$_POST['field7'][$i]. "', '" .$_POST['field8'][$i]. "', '" .$_POST['field9'][$i]. "', '".$my."', '".$sem."', '".$subj."', '".$branch."')";
        }

$query1 = "INSERT INTO paper (question, marks_allotted, complexity, chp_no, tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, monthandyear, semester, subject_name, branch_name) VALUES " . implode(", ", $insertArr);

mysql_query($query1) or trigger_error("Insert failed: " . mysql_error());


    }

echo("<pre>\n");
print_r($_POST);
echo("</pre>\n");

mysql_close($id_link);
?>
```

On running, gives me the following **despite the fact that the questions that i enter have no matching tags with the existing ones in the db**:
No entry entered for Entry #0 since it may lead to duplicates. No entry entered for Entry #1 since it may lead to duplicates.
Notice: Undefined variable: insertArr on line 41

Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed on line 41

Notice: Insert failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' on line 43

**Guide me please**

Comment: Give us some code maybe..?

Comment: i have not started writing it actually. I only have my queries for inserting data.

Comment: Okay, I'll read the question again and try to help. Sorry :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072036/insert-multiple-records-in-mysql-with-one-php-form

Comment: thank you for the link :) hopefully i can use the example and start writing my code!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have for example

```
<input type="text" name="tag1" />
<input type="text" name="tag2" />
```

POSTed from the form to PHP

then you have in the PHP

```
$tag1 = $_POST['tag1']; $tag2 = $_POST['tag2'];
$sql = "SELECT tag1, tag2 FROM db1 WHERE tag1 = '$tag1' OR tag2 = '$tag2';";
//query the $sql value i.e. with $query = mysql_query($sql) (which is not good example since its deprecated)
//then make a check:
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num > 0) {
echo "There are matches with one or more tags you've entered";
}
else {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO db1 (tag1, tag2) VALUES ('$tag1', '$tag2')");
echo "Tags inserted";
}
```

Have in mind the example is very poor and not good designed, but I hope you get the idea. There are equivalent ways in other sql libs for found row, so you have to selected if there are matches, and if true - make them change their tags.

Comment: okay, now that i have a rough idea about what my code should be, i have one more doubt. If matching tags are found, i do not want that question to be inserted at all i.e. ignored. So what piece of code will do that for me?

Answer (score 0):

this code from the first answer will do that

```
if ($num > 0) {
```

echo "There are matches with one or more tags you've entered";
}

if the number is greater than one this code will execute and the insert block will be ignored